# Typeorm MySQL where column like search text not working in queryBuilder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

this is my query builder:

```
const users = await this.userRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select(['firstName', 'lastName'])
  .where('LOWER(firstName) LIKE :search', {
    search: `%${query.search.toLowerCase()}%`,
  })
  .getRawMany();
```

the error:
EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property "search" was not found in "User". Make sure your query is correct.

firstName & lastName both are valid User properties. I've tried it like this as well:

```
const users = await this.dataSource
  .getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select(['firstName', 'lastName'])
  .where('LOWER(firstName) LIKE :search', {
    search: `%${query.search.toLowerCase()}%`,
  })
  .getRawMany();
```

but its the same. Db is mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const lowercaseName = query.search.toLowerCase();
const users = await this.userRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select(['firstName', 'lastName'])
  .where(
    // Omit this `User.` if not needed, it will work without it
    `MATCH(LOWER(User.firstName)) AGAINST(:name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`,
    {
      name: `*${lowercaseName}*`,
    },
  )
  .getRawMany();

const rawQuery = queryBuilder.getSql();
console.log(rawQuery) // this will log raw query, u can test this raw query in mysql
```

**This `AGAINST SEARCH` will require `FULLTEXT-INDEX` on firstname column**

**To resolve this, run this migration :**

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class AddFullTextIndexToUser1612345678901 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE User ADD FULLTEXT INDEX idx_user_firstName (firstName)`
    );
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE User DROP INDEX idx_user_firstName`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,  I got it working the other way

Answer (score 0):

I created a NestJS project, added the Typeorm library, and used the code that you added in your question but everything works fine. I uploaded the code of the project on Github, here is the link (https://github.com/pablosalazzar/stackoverflow-answer-1), so you can compare the code.

Comment: yeah, after posting the question, I realized that there was some other code that was causing error. And after that, I did  answer it myself, but now I see that the answer wasn't posted (weird). However, I thank you to put your time into this. Really appreciate it.